# Create a table with column default to current date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to create a column that will have a default date (just date not time) but its giving me error.

```
 CREATE TABLE MEMBERS
(mem_id NUMBER (4),
Comp_name VARCHAR2 (30) NOT NULL,
Email VARCHAR2 (30),
Last_date DATE DEFAULT GETDATE(),
Con_cnt NUMBER (3) CHECK (Con_cnt>0),
CONSTRAINT Con_cnt_pk PRIMARY KEY (mem_id)
);
```

Comment: Do you use Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: thank you, this has been resolved, I used sysdate instead of GETDATE and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used sysdate instead of GETDATE, it worked

Comment: It appears that you are using Oracle, not MySQL, for your database so I've edited the tags on your question.  Be aware that an Oracle `date` always has a day and a time.  You say in your question that you don't want a time but `sysdate` includes the current time to the second.  Perhaps you want to `trunc` the `date` to always set the time component to midnight.